# Scala Pattern Matching Enigma

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Here's my attempt of the 3rd problem (P03) of the 99 Problems in Scala (http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/):

```
import scala.annotation._

// Find the nth element of a list.
// nth(2, List(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8)) = 2

object P03 {
  @tailrec def nth[A](n: Int, ls: List[A]): A = (n, ls) match {
    case (0, h :: t :: Nil) => h
    case (n, _ :: t)        => nth(n - 1, t)
    case _                  => println(n); throw new IllegalArgumentException
}
```

The enigma is that this code prints `-4` and throws an `IllegalArgumentException`

The solution of course is to change the first pattern to:

```
case (0, h :: _) => h
```

This now prints the correct answer `2`

Question is Why? What is the subtle difference between:

```
case (0, h :: t :: Nil) => h
```

&

```
case (0, h :: _) => h
```

Thanks!

Comment: The difference is that `h :: t :: Nil` matches only a list with two elements (`h` and `t`, `Nil` is the marker for the end of a list) while `h :: _` matches every non empty list, ie a list that has at least one element.

Comment: Can you add this as an answer instead of a comment. I would like to mark it as the answer and close it :). Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that `h :: t :: Nil` matches only a list with two elements (`h` and `t`, `Nil` is the marker for the end of a list (I'm not 100% sure it's the exact nomenclature)) while `h :: _` matches every non empty list, ie a list that has at least one element, if you check the `::` class you'll see:

```
final case class ::[B](private var hd: B, private[scala] var tl: List[B]) extends List[B]
```

Which has a head and a tail where the first is the first element of the list and the second is the rest, matching on `h :: t :: Nil` means getting the first element of the list, than the first of the tail and then there should be a `Nil`, matching on `h :: _` means getting the head and then you don't care of what's left as long as there's a head.